# Repair permissions on El Capitan OS X from Recovery mode

Tags: macos, permissions, osx-el-capitan

I would like to repair my accidentaly changed permission, but I don't know, how to execute this command `sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs /` from Recovery mode console ... At first, it throws something about unknown sudo and if I will remove it, it will throws something about no packages found on this disk. Could anyone help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Is there any reason you're not doing it from the booted OS? Recovery probably doesn't have the packages to compare to, even if it recognises the command. Maybe giving it the full path would help... /Volumes/Macintosh HD/...

Comment: The OS doesnt boot... And now with your help I've executed the command correctly, it repaired a lot of things, but OS still doesnt boot :( I've accidentally run sudo chmod -R 777 /

Comment: I have the same problem. I think my system doesn’t boot because of permissions, and I can’t repair them because of that no packages found thing